# Javascript min max

Tags: javascript, floating-point, max, min

In PHP you can use this to keep a number between 2 values, minimum and maximum:

`$n = min(max($n, 1), 20);`

so if $n is larger than 20 it will take the value of 20.
If it's smaller than 1 it will take the value of 1. Otherwise it will not change

How can I do this in javascript / jQuery ?

Comment: this is actually bad code. to write a generic limiter in almost any common language it would be as easy as this :

function limiter (L, n, H) { return n > H ? H : (n < L ? L : n); }

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's pretty much the same in JavaScript, only that `min` and `max` are members of the `Math` object:

```
var n = Math.min(Math.max(n, 1), 20);
```

Comment: For those of us who are addicted to extending the Math object: `Math.limit = function (min, num, max) { return Math.max(min, Math.min(num, max)); }`

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript has [`Math.min` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and [`Math.max` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max).

Alternatively, you can use the conditional operator:

```
n = n > 20 ? 20 : (n < 1 ? 1 : n)
```

Comment: This is perhaps better than Tim Cooper answer because it is more generic as it will work with any JS type that can be compared with intrinsic bigger-than and lower-than comparators.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with min and max, but I think `if` is clearer.

```
if (x > 20) x = 20;
if (x < 1) x = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't take the max and min of variables.  However, it's easy just to push your variables into an array and find the max and min of the array (with a slightly different syntax):

```
var value1 = 5;
var value2 = 25;
var value3 = -3;

var arr = [];
arr.push(value1);
arr.push(value2);
arr.push(value3);

var maxValue = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
var minValue = Math.min.apply(null, arr);

alert(maxValue);// ==25
alert(minValue);// ==-3
```

or equivalently

```
var value1 = 5;
var value2 = 25;
var value3 = -3;

var maxValue = Math.max.apply(null, [value1, value2, value3]);
var minValue = Math.min.apply(null, [value1, value2, value3]);

alert(maxValue);// ==25
alert(minValue);// ==-3
```

Comment: Felix Kling solution is better. It is generic. Not just for numbers. But then the original question is a bit moot admittedly.